# Flutter - Json.decode return incorrect json

Tags: json, dart, flutter

Recently I change all JSON of my app to show the errors, messages, and body of the service. In the body, I have an array of data. Before I change the JSON, all worked doing something like this:

```
final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
```

Which returned:

> [{"id":1,"descripcion":"Terreno Rio"},{"id":2,"descripcion":"Terreno
>   Asier"}]

Now I try to do something like this:

```
final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
print(json.encode(responseJson));
```

Which returns:

> [{"code":0,"message":"","body":[{"id":1,"descripcion":"Terreno
>   Rio"},{"id":2,"descripcion":"Terreno Asier"}]}]

Does anybody know the right way to extract some element of the JSON and decode?

Comment: This looks like what `List.toString()` produces. This is not JSON, this is just a string representation of a Dart data structure for debugging purposes. Are you sure this is the output from `print(json.encode(responseJson));` and not from `print(responseJson)`?

Comment: I Mistake, you right. Anyway i don´t know how can i extract the body element of this json. I update question.

Comment: did you read [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)?

Comment: "the right way to extract some element of the json and decode" Not sure what that means. Normally you decode and get a List or Map and then access the elements in that List or Map.

Comment: Imagine you have [{"code":0,"message":"","body":[{"id":1,"descripcion":"Terreno Rio"},{"id":2,"descripcion":"Terreno Asier"}]}] i want only elements after body 'tag'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the JSON response that you get is like this:

> {"code":0,"message":"","body":[{"id":1,"descripcion":"Terreno
>   Rio"},{"id":2,"descripcion":"Terreno Asier"}]}

So in order to parse that JSON, you can just access the body directly:

```
List list = responseJson['body'];
```

Now you can iterate through the elements of the array:

```
for (Map<String, dynamic> element in list) {
    print(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a `List` of `Maps`. First access the first element (there is only 1) of the `List` with `[0]` and then the `body` element of the returned `Map` with `['body']`:

```
var body = responseJson[0]['body'];
print(body);
```

Comment: If i try you code returns  '[{id: 1, descripcion: Terreno Rio}, {id: 2, descripcion: Terreno Asier}]' without "" so flutter can't identify the names of elements and the data.

Comment: "so flutter can't identify the names of elements and the data". I don't understand how you came to that conclusion. If you want class instances containing that data then you need to read the link pskink posted above. There is no unique way to map JSON to classes, you need to specify that mapping explicitly using code.